# Ad is opened in WebView of app instead of default browser while pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-webview

I have build webview app with 2 activityes: webview and adMob.
Both are working fine together. The only problem is that when user press ad, it's loading in webview of the app instead of browser. But the links are mean to be for Google Play so when user press ad there is an error: "ERR_UNKNONWN_URL_SCHEME".
How do I open it in browser while ad pressed?

Can someone please tell me a solution for my problem.
It's quite emergency!
Here are the AdMobActivity.java, MainActivity.java and main_activity.xml

**AdMobActivity.java**

```
package com.example.www.probe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;



public class AdMobActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

}
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
package com.example.www.probe;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebview ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String
description, String failingUrl) {

            }
        });
        mWebview .loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(mWebview.canGoBack() == true){
                        mWebview.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.www.probe.MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Layout screenschot]

Note: In the strings file are only app name and ad_unit_id.

Comment: You're not actually loading AdMobActivity anywhere. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i am trying that the ad is opened in browser when clicked